# how to get google drive Storage Quota

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using `Google Drive API` in android for listing, uploading and downloading files of Google Drive and I have successfully implemented it.

Now i want User `Storage Quota` like how much space user has used and how much is left. Can any one suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve quota info from `about` resource by making an authenticated call to

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about
```

which is going to return an [about entity](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource) with `quotaBytesTotal` and `quotaBytesUsed`.